# how to remove hash tag in ie8 while using history.js

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

i want to remove the hash tag from url 
So, if I have http://example.com#exist, how do I remove #exist.
and make it like http://example.com/exist

Comment: what do you want really? if i open your link i have already this url: http://example.com/exist

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your browser - 
If you're using a browser that has HTML5 History API compatibility - and you have the history.js options default settings as well as using the pushState correctly, you should be able to see the updated URL without the hash.

If you're using a HTML4 browser, the history API won't remove the hash within your updated URL.

A tip you can use is that if you were to use the history.js pushState/replaceState
Keep a note of appending a "/" before your url change. eg

```
History.pushState({"State": "Exist"}, null, "/exist");
```

Answer (score 0):

No Its not possible, In IE8 you have to make only Hash change, you cannot make it '/exist' without reloading.  Read more about [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/). It will help you..